# Determinant ratio approaching one-half

Tags: limits, determinant

Let $\det M(n)$ be the generalization of this $5 \times 5$ determinant:

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 \\
 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 2 \\
 4 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 5 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{vmatrix}
= 1875 \;.
$$

I'd like to prove that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|\det M(n) \,|}{n^n}  = \frac{1}{2} \;.
$$
For example, $$\frac{\det M(5)}{5^5} = \frac{1875}{3125} = 0.6\;,$$
but by $n=200$ the ratio is $0.5025$.

Comment: Here is an explicit formula for the determinant of that circulant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3437818/42969

Comment: @MartinR: Thanks. I did not know the terminology "circulant matrix."

Comment: According to the formula given there, $\frac{|\det M(n) \,|}{n^n} = \frac{1+n}{2n}$.